# How does saturate_cast in OpenCV work?

Tags: opencv

Unable to understand, the results of the expression Vxy and Vxy_nocast

```
uchar init_m0[] = {10,10,30};
cv::Mat m0(3,1,CV_8UC1,init_m0,sizeof(uchar));
uchar& Vxy = m0.at<uchar>(0);
uchar& Vxy_nocast = m0.at<uchar>(1);
std::cout << m0 << std::endl;
Vxy = cv::saturate_cast<uchar>((Vxy-128)*2 + 128);
Vxy_nocast = (Vxy_nocast-128)*2 + 128;
std::cout << m0 << std::endl;
```

Result

```
[ 10;
  10;
  30]
[  0;
 148;
  30]
```

Comment: saturate cast will make sure that no integer over- or underflows occur. Typically if you have an unsigned char variable value 200 and add 56 (+ X) you'll get an overflow and variable will have value 0 (+ X) which is very very bad for many algorithms.

Comment: In this case I'd say [code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/saturate.hpp#L102) is the best place to look for an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(10-128)*2 + 128 = -108`. `cv::saturate_cast<uchar>` is a saturating cast to unsigned char, and unsigned char can only be >= 0. A normal uchar cast, which is what happens implicitly if you specify nothing, will wrap a negative value around to positive by just reinterpreting the bits, -108 is `10010100` in 2's complement binary, which is the same as 148 (and it will also wrap around a larger value, eg 257 to 1). A saturating cast instead will cast negative values to 0, saturating at the minimum value of 0 for the type (and likewise positive values will saturate at the maximum of 255).

See [saturation arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic) for more details.

Comment: so, the saturation_cast has one added step in this case. It is looking for the MSB and if the MSB is 1, then make the result 0. In a normal cast, it would just truncate from 32 bit to 8 bit and display the result in 2s complement?

Comment: Kind of, but it is looking beyond the 8 bits of an unsigned char to determine if it is either too big or too small. This extra step may not be any more expensive than a normal add if it is running on hardware with support for saturation arithmetic.

Comment: The question is not tagged with a language, so what does happen with Python bindings? Saturated arithmetic is the default way for operations on OpenCV matrices, e.g. `imgblend = 0.2*img1 + 0.8*img2` will produce the expected result with OpenCV matrices, but with images stored in Python Numpy arrays, saturation must be done explicitly: `imgblend  = cv2.add(0.2*img1, 0.8*img2)` to ensure no rounding leads to an overflow.